# Redirect one relative path to another in Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a folder with a lot of typescript files that import modules like `../path1/module1/subModule` and so on.

I want to redirect such imports using Webpack to `../../another/path2/module1/subModule`.

I tried using webpack resolve .alias in such way, but it seems doesn't work:

```
alias:
 {
   '../path1': '../../another/path2',
 },
```

Could you help with the solution?